# notepad++ removing NON-alphabetics from text

Tags: notepad++, regex

My text contains an entire range of non-Alphabetic symbols (&^%$#-0-9 ./) I want to remove.

if this replaces all alphabetic characters:

```
Find what: ([a-z,A-Z]) 
replace with:
```

Why does this not replace anything?:

```
Find what: (![a-z,A-Z]) 
replace with:
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has multiple duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149759/remove-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-a-string-array-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167385/filter-non-alphabetic-characters-out-of-string-in-shell-script Granted, non-superUser duplicates, but still extremely easy to find when pasting the title in google...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "!" is not what I thought it was in this case
The correct expression should have been:

```
find what: [^a-z]
replace with:
```

The, "A-Z", is not necessary in Notepad++ because there is "Match Case" switch.
Also, the "(" and  ")" are redundant.

Comment: Yep. Also, [a-z,A-Z] will match all letters, and *also* the comma! You do not need to add a comma to sepparate multiple characters. If you would have used this, it should have been [a-zA-Z].